# Completely disable the swipe back gesture throughout the entire app

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to disable the swipe back gesture that allows users to go back.
I've tried:

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) { 
 self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO; 
}
```

and all sorts of other code I've found online, but none of them work at all? I'm using iOS 8.3.
Is there a way to disable this all together? Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. You are breaking a common interaction that all iPhone users know and have used in every app o the phone. Breaking this just makes your app more frustrating to use to the point where people won't use it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all as @Fogmeister said in comments, you need to have a very good reason to remove this native function to your app.

Now, having said this, the solution:

[SwipeBack](https://github.com/devxoul/SwipeBack) and [JRSwizzle](https://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle) (Needed by SwipeBack)

You can use this in a single ViewController in which you want to remove the functionality or you create a custom class for UINavigationController and you use it there:

```
#import <SwipeBack/SwipeBack.h>

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
//For a single viewcontroller
    self.navigationController.swipeBackEnabled = NO;

//If you are in the custom class
self.swipeBackEnabled = NO;
}
```

Hope it helps.